# React hook form onchage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

So, i am trying to add a file to my form. I create a custom component for it to create a preview of a picture that user is submitting. The problem is react-hook-form takes the onChange function in the ...register, and i need this function to create a preview for an image.

```
<Uploader
          name="image"
          id="image"
          label="Pick an Image"
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
          rules={{
            required: "This field is required!"
          }}
          setValue={setValue}
        />
```

This is where i create a custom input and pass the register to it. Then i have this component and use onChange function to put a file into the state and i create a preview for it.

```
const Uploader = (props) => {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState()
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState()

  const {register, name, label, errors, rules, setValue} = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!selectedFile) {
      setPreview(undefined)
      return
    }

    const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile)
    setPreview(objectUrl)

  }, [selectedFile])

  const onSelectFile = e => {
    if (!e.target.files || e.target.files.length === 0) {
      setSelectedFile(undefined)
      return
    }
    setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])
    setValue("image", e.target.files[0])
  }
    return (
      <div className="imageUpload">
        <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
        <input
          {...register("image", rules)}
          id="image"
          name="image"
          type="file"
          accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg"
          onChange={onSelectFile}
        />
        {selectedFile &&  <div className="imageUploadPreview"><img className="imageUploadPreview" src={preview} alt="Preview of a Picture"/></div> }
      </div>
    );
}
```

I tried to set the image field with setValue function, but i cannot press the button to submit the form, it does not count file in validity of form and thinks it's empty, even I used setValue.
Maybe there are any other options to combine the creating of a preview and a register?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution: you have to pass onChange function into a register object

```
{...register("image", {onChange: onSelectFile})}
```

And that's it